# Are there one instance of ActivityManager for each activity in Android?

Tags: android, operating-system

I added a static field to ActivityManager and set it in my activity. When I exit my activity and enter again, I found that the value has been restored to defaults. I wonder if it means that there is an instance of activity manager for each activity?

Basically in ActivityManager I added the following things:

```
public static boolean s = false;
public void setS(boolean b) { s = b; }
public boolean getS() { return s; }
```

Then I compiled OS and in my app I use reflection to access the above methods. If I do not quit my app, then whatever get set in the setS method are reflected in the getS method. If I quit the app and enter again, then getS always return false. Wonder why?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Because you have made this `static` it belongs not to an *instance* (in the OO or Java meaning of the word) but rather to a *process*.  Given that you've managed to access this with JNI, it must be in your Application's own process, and not in some system one interacted with via IPC.  Therefore, the lifetime of this variable is the lifetime of your application process.  This tells you next to nothing about how ActivityManager normally works.

Answer (score 0):

ActivityManager Interact with the overall activities running in the system.
Save your value to SharedPreferences. You need to set value again onstart() and onresume() and save value to SharedPreferences in onStop(), onDestroy()

When you quit app all activities destroyed that the reason getS() function returns false because app restart and your boolean value set again.

Comment: This doesn't really seem very targeted to the question asked, which seems to be more about understanding the system by experimental modification, rather than by storing useful data in a way that might be better done with a normal mechanism such as SharedPreferences.